# React won't batch setState calls inside event handler if there's an await call before or between them

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await, react-hooks, setstate

I've found this interesting React behavior that I would like to know more about.

Usually React will batch multiple `setState()` calls when inside an event handler, right?

But I tested that React won't batch the calls if:

- The event handler function is an `async` function with a an `await` call.
- And that `await` call executes **before or between** the `setState()` calls.

  - If the `await` runs after the `setState()` calls, they are batched as usual.

**QUESTION:**

Do you know what is the reason behind this?

---

**CodeSandbox:** https://codesandbox.io/s/eventhandlerawaitso-jsdxs

**This is the `mockAPI` call**

```
function mockAPI() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        resolve("I come from API using an AWAIT call");
      },500);
    });
  }
```

**These are the handlers to test:**

```
function handleClickNormal() {
    console.clear();

    console.log("Calling 1st setState()");
    updateBooleanState(false);

    console.log("Calling 2nd setState()");
    updateBooleanState(true);

    console.log("After 2nd setState()");
  }

  async function handleClickAwaitBefore() {
    console.clear();

    // AWAIT CALL RUNS BEFORE THE setState CALLS
    const fromAPI = await mockAPI();
    console.log(fromAPI);

    console.log("Calling 1st setState()");
    updateBooleanState(false);

    console.log("Calling 2nd setState()");
    updateBooleanState(true);

    console.log("After 2nd setState()");
  }

  async function handleClickAwaitAfter() {
    console.clear();

    console.log("Calling 1st setState()");
    updateBooleanState(false);

    console.log("Calling 2nd setState()");
    updateBooleanState(true);

    console.log("After 2nd setState()");

    // AWAIT CALL RUNS AFTER THE setState CALLS
    const fromAPI = await mockAPI();
    console.log(fromAPI);
  }

  async function handleClickAwaitBetween() {
    console.clear();

    console.log("Calling 1st setState()");
    updateBooleanState(false);

    // AWAIT CALL RUNS BETWEEN THE setState CALLS
    const fromAPI = await mockAPI();
    console.log(fromAPI);

    console.log("Calling 2nd setState()");
    updateBooleanState(true);

    console.log("After 2nd setState()");
  }
```

**This is the result:**

[image]

**Comments**

We can see that the `setState()` calls are batched if there are **no** `await` calls *(Click Normal)* and if the `await` call comes **after** the `setState()` *(Click Await After).*

And that the `setState()` calls are NOT batched if there's an `await` call **before** *(Click Await Before)* or **between** the `setState()` calls *(Click Await Between).*

Comment: Isn't this just the nature of async javascript? `await` will open a gap in the execution queue, allowing a render to "slip in". Havin the `await` before or after setState keeps the execution queue full, not allowing renders. I don't know anything about React setState, but this does not look unusual to me.

Comment: guess it would not be nice if react batched awaits that could potentially take 10 seconds each

Comment: When the await is between, it makes total sense. But the await before is really strange to me. Because that handler will be paused (with generators internally or something) untill that asyn call resolves or reject, right? How would that change the behavior of what's coming after? Or maybe just by using the `async` word, React would not batch anything. But the fact that the order matters is what has got me thinking.

Comment: cool question :-)

Comment: Re: the question above in the comments: I'll assume, that the rendering is a tiny bit delayed, to allow any state modification to finish before re-rendering. This is a common technique to batch changes (ie. `setTimeout(doRender)`). So, assuming all `setState` calls are synchronous, that simple timeout would make sure all `setState` calls would finish (because they're blocking) before `setTimeout()` finishes. But this is from basic JS, not very React specific.

Answer (score 2):

Async programming is very much about call stacks and event loops.
You can find a lot about it in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ

So, when you have `await`s in between, `setState`s will fall into different stacks.
I believe this is the main reason why react doesn't batch them.

Answer (score 0):

First, let's see what Dan Abramov has to say about [this matter](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/10231#issuecomment-316644950):

> In current release, they will be batched together if you are inside a React event handler. React batches all setStates done during a React event handler, and applies them just before exiting its own browser event handler.
>
> With current version, several setStates outside of event handlers (e.g. in network responses) will not be batched. So you would get two re-renders in that case.

Hmmm, so we can do setState from React event handler and outside of it. React event handler is the function we pass as a prop to the component.

If we take `handleClickAwaitBefore` and rewrite it without async-await we get something like this:

```
 function handleClickAwaitBefore() {
    console.clear();

    // Here we are in event handler and setState is batched
    mockAPI().then(function notEventHandlerAnyMore(){
       
       // Here we are in totally different function and setState is not batched any more
       console.log(fromAPI);

       console.log("Calling 1st setState()");
       updateBooleanState(false);

       console.log("Calling 2nd setState()");
       updateBooleanState(true);

       console.log("After 2nd setState()"); 
    })

  }
```